# How to interpret the UPS spectrum of quantum dots?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, photoelectric-effect, light-emitting-diodes

I have been using the ultraviolet photoemission spectroscopy (**UPS**) to look at the energy levels of **quantum dots**. My quantum dot has a core/shell structure, where the shell is supposed to have a larger bandgap.

But how can one tell the **valence bands** of the core and shell respectively from the spectrum?

Also, there appears a relatively significant shoulder at the **secondary-electron edge**. I wonder why is that and how should I determine the cut-off?
[image]